# How to run LibreOffice 6.2 on CentOS6 / RHEL6?

Tags: centos6, libreoffice, rhel6

I can install LO RPMs but when I try to run the process I get this:

```
/opt/libreoffice6.2/program/oosplash: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.3.4' not found (required by /opt/libreoffice6.2/program/oosplash)
/opt/libreoffice6.2/program/oosplash: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/libreoffice6.2/program/oosplash)
/opt/libreoffice6.2/program/oosplash: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /opt/libreoffice6.2/program/libuno_sal.so.3)
/opt/libreoffice6.2/program/oosplash: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/libreoffice6.2/program/libuno_sal.so.3)
```

Indeed CentOS6 / RHEL6 have a bit older deps.
I wonder if anyone managed to run LibreOffice 6.2 on this OS?

Comment: TDF LibreOffice 6.2 64 bit builds are done on CentOS 7 and therefore incompatible with RHEL 6. However the code should still compile on RHEL with the developer toolset if you disable gtk3 and kde5 gui backends.